# Adding PubNub AnnotationProcessor in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, pubnub

I'm trying to set up the PubNub jar as a library in my Android Studio project. The project is something I am porting over from another computer, so I'm mostly copying things in.

It appears between then and now that I now have to configure the AnnotationProcessor of this jar, but I'm really not sure what that requires, nor have I been able to find an example that fits my issue.

When I try to compile my project, I am left with this message:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
 Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'. 

Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now. 
The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.
Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration- pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar (pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar).

Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.
Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error- message.html for more details.
```

I'm really not sure at all what this is telling me to do, and the examples I can find of annotationprocessor on the internet (none for PubNub) all are pointing to packages and classes, which I don't see what I am suppose to do with.

Can someone lead me down the correct path?

I apologize for the formatting of the error, but the site wouldn't let me submit it in blockquotes because it was "improperly formatted code."

Comment: I will have our Android engineer review this in the event that the PubNub jars need to have some additional config/manifest or whatever for the annotation things, but the error message does provide an alternative for the short term: `android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true` - can you configure that for now until we have a definitive answer?

Comment: According to your Android engineering, please add this line in your `dependencies{}` block:
`annotationProcessor files('libs/pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar')` 
along with the `implementation files('libs/pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar')`. Let us know if that resolves issue for you so we can formalize this into an official answer to this post.

Comment: That is indeed the solution. Seems rather simple now that I look at it, but there wasn't any resource I could find that suggested what to do to resolve an issue like that in an external jar library. What I was finding were things like "extract the annotationprocessor from the jar and set it up independently" and other long, tedious, and generally ambiguous solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this line in your `dependencies{}` block:

`annotationProcessor files('libs/pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar')`

(along with the `implementation files('libs/pubnub-gson-4.19.0-all.jar')`)

It works in my case.

Comment: Nice answer steal ;)